# MongoDB schema analyzer (reverse engineering)

Tags: data-analysis, mongodb, schema

I am looking for some free / FOSS tool that could go through my MongoDB data and provide a parsable report of what structure lies there in, and what's the frequency of that.

For instance, I have a collection, where documents have some properties, some nested documents, some arrays.

I would like to see a report with the info like:

```
name: String in 99.9% | null in 0.01 %
assets: array in 51 % | String in 49 % ("none": 100 %)
assets[]: document in 31 % | String in 25 %
assets[].id: String in 100 % cases
```

etc.
Not particularly in this format, but this kind of information.

I know that Studio3T can do that, but only in the paid version, $700/year.

But what I need is not too complicated, just a bit of sampling and aggregating the statistics, and returning a JSON or such.
So I believe there is already some such tool.

I prefer FOSS because I won't let a random binary on the potentially sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

I found one, quite obvious:  MongoDB Compass can do that, on the Schema tab of a collection. To export to JSON, there's a menu `Collection -> Share schema`.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/schema/export/

Not automated, but good enough.

Then there's Variety, https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/meet-variety-a-schema-analyzer-for-mongodb
Which is automatable, but the output is not too exhaustive.